# Change PowerShell ISE Keyboard Shortcuts

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, powershell-ise

Is it possible with a registry hack or another mechanism to change the default shortcuts in PowerShell ISE? I'd like to modify the debugging shortcuts to be keys that I use in other applications for consistency.

Comment: May be not. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/8014749/

Answer (score 1):

This should help ( example of re-assigning the CTRL+M shortcut that toggles outlining ): [stackoverflow.com/questions/53577234](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53577234/custom-keyboard-shortcuts-in-powershell-ise)
.. from the post:

```
$Display = "Select Current Line"
$Action = { $psise.CurrentFile.Editor.SelectCaretLine() }
$Shortcut = "Ctrl+L"
$psise.CurrentPowerShellTab.AddOnsMenu.Submenus.Add($Display,$Action,$shortcut)
```